# How do I get email ids of friends the user sent requests to?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook on my website to send requests. (like a multi friend selector)

I am using the a basic method in fb documentation as

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=APP_ID&message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&redirect_uri=http://localhost/mysite/newpage.aspx
```

It works and sends requests and I get the id'd of the users requests are sent to.

Now, How do I get their email address ? 
I would like to store both facebook id and email addresses of all the people requests are sent to.

In fact, it would be of great help if I can get some basic details like email, first and last name, facebook profile picture etc., for all those ids.

I am using asp.net. Please try to answer in that.

Answer (score 1):

That's simply not possible - there's no way the Facebook Graph API would expose Email-addresses of friends! (you can of course access the email-address of the current user when authorizing with the "email"-extended permission).

As for the other basic details - yeah, firstname, lastname & profile picture are publicly available, just query https://graph.facebook.com/USERID?fields=first_name,last_name,picture. You should consider using Batch-Requests if you want to query lots of different persons in one go.

Comment: Hi, after I have the user's authentication How do I get their friends list ?

Comment: The user is just logged into my application now. How do I ask for extended permission now ??

Comment: You get the friendlist with the Graph API call /me/friends.
Extended permissions are handled with the scope-parameter: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/